# I am having EPERM Error while trying to load a new Ganache workspace

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

```
`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
```

rename 'C:\Users...\workspaces\smiling-cover\Settings.2447570826'
-> 'C:\Users...\workspaces\smiling-cover\Settings'`

- Already tried `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: There is probably still a handle to the deleted `Settings` folder open. It is then hidden but the name still exists and the new settings folder cannot be renamed to the same name. Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Maybe run the task as administrator, this is a windows OS-level thing